Matplotlib annotations do not appear at the proper distance in graph
I have subset of countries where I am comparing gdp per person and geographic latitude. I've developed code down here:
country_sub.plot(kind='scatter', figsize=(6, 4), grid=True, x=lat_col, y=gdp_ppp_col)

gdp_ppp_col = "gdp_ppp"
lat_col = "lat"

position_text = {
    "Israel": (31.04605, 57_758),
    "United States": (37.09024, 75_269),
    "Spain": (40.463667, 29_385),
    "Bulgaria": (42.733883, 13_129),
    "Germany": (51.165691, 48_845),
    "Ireland": (53.41291, 105_362),
    "Iceland": (64.963051, 74_663)
}

for country, pos_text in position_text.items():
    pos_data_x = country_sub[lat_col].loc[country]
    pos_data_y = country_sub[gdp_ppp_col].loc[country]
    country = "U.S." if country == "United States" else country
    plt.annotate(country,
                xy=(pos_data_x, pos_data_y),
                xytext=pos_text,
                fontsize=12, 
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='->')
                )
    plt.plot(pos_data_x, pos_data_y, "ro")

plt.axis([25, 70, -5000, 125000])

plt.show()

However this results in the following graph:

Is there a way to move the country annotations to the backends of the arrows?

Try adding to xytext:
...
    plt.annotate(country,
                xy=(pos_data_x, pos_data_y),
                xytext=(pos_text[0] + 10, pos_text[1] + 10),
                fontsize=12, 
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='->')
                )
...

